# Navbar and footer doesn't take up full width of browser

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

There's still a gap in the right side of the navbar and footer. I'm running this on Safari. Please help me figure this out. Thank you in advance. I'm also using Bootstrap and trying to avoid Javascript.

Here's my HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Elysian</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9">
          <img src="assets/white logo.png" class="logo" alt="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <a href="#" class = "header-heart-icon"><i class ="fa fa-heart-o"></i></a>
          <p id="header-wishlist"><a href="#">Wishlist</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="expand">
          <p id="header-cart">Shopping List</p>
          <p id="cart-item"> Chloé [1] $14,200</p>
          <p id="cart-item"> Aquazzura [1] $4,425</p>
          <hr>
          <p>TOTAL</p>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Check Out</button>
        </div>
      </div> 
        <!-- Add the hover to shopping list-->
    </header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="clothes.html">Clothing</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="shoes.html">Shoes</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="bags.html">Bags</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <ul class="breadcrumb">
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="intro">
      <h5 class="home-heading">New in: handpicked daily from the world's best brands</h5>
    </div>

    <div class="wrap">
         
      <div class="box">
          <div class="product-box">
            <a href="acne-studios.html"><img src="assets/Clothing/Acne Studios abstract-print T-shirt.png" class="product-thumbnail" alt="Acne Studios"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="add-wishlist">
            <a href="#" class = "product-heart-icon"><i class ="fa fa-heart-o"></i></a>
          </div>
          <div class="text">
            <!-- Here, product-name is the brand -->
            <h5 id ="product-name"><a href="acne-studios.html">Acne Studios</a></h5>
            <p id="product-description">abstract-print T-shirt</p>
            <p id="product-price"> HK$2,100</p>
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Add to Cart</button>
      </div>

      <div class="box">
        <div class="product-box">
          <a href="aquazurra.html"><img src="assets/Shoes/Aquazzura Saint Honore 50mm ankle boots.png" class="product-thumbnail" alt="Aquazzura"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="add-wishlist">
          <a href="#" class = "product-heart-icon"><i class ="fa fa-heart-o"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <h5 id ="product-name"><a href="aquazurra.html">Aquazzura</a></h5>
          <p id="product-description">Saint Honore 50mm ankle boots</p>
          <p id="product-price">HK$4,425</p>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Add to Cart</button>
      </div>

      <div class="box">
        <div class="product-box">
          <a href="chloé.html"><img src="assets/Bags/Chloé small Woody leather tote bag.png" class="product-thumbnail" alt="Chloé"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="add-wishlist">
          <a href="#" class = "product-heart-icon"><i class ="fa fa-heart-o"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <h5 id ="product-name"><a href="chloé.html">Chloé</a></h5>
          <p id="product-description">small Woody leather tote bag</p>
          <p id="product-price">HK$14,200</p>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Add to Cart</button>
      </div>
      
    </div>

    <footer class="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="footer-col">
            <h4>Customer Service</h4>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Orders and delivery</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Payment and pricing</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="footer-col">
            <h4>About Elysian</h4>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Investors</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Elysian partner boutiques</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="footer-col">
            <h4>Discounts and membership</h4>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Affiliate program</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Refer a friend</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Elysian membership</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="footer-col">
            <h4>Follow us</h4>
            <div class="social-links">
              <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
              <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official"></i></a>
              <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest-p"></i></a>
              <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: white;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;
}

/* Styles the list */
ul.breadcrumb {
    padding-top: 16px;
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 60px;
}
  
/* Display items side by side */
ul.breadcrumb li {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 15px;
}
  
/* Add a > symbol before/behind each list item */
ul.breadcrumb li+li:before {
    padding: 8px;
    color: #800020;
    content: ">";
}
  
/* Add color to all links inside the list */
ul.breadcrumb li a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.logo {
    max-width: 130px; 
    display: block;
    margin-left: 35px;
}

.header-heart-icon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 275px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.header-cart-icon {
    padding-right: 2px;
}

.expand {
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 5%;
    width: 9%;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    z-index: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2.4%;
    right: 3.4%;
    color: black;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.expand:hover {
    height: 230px;
    width: 26vw;
    z-index: 10;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.navbar { 
    padding: 5px 40px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: black;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-link.active {
    color: #800020;
}

a {
    color: black;
}

.intro {
    margin-left: 10%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 45%;
}

.home-heading {
    font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 90px;
}

.intro-title {
    font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.intro-desc {
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}

.product-box {
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 10px; 
    background: #fafafa;
    height: 300px;
    max-width: 250px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.product-thumbnail {
    max-width: 230px;
    width:100%;
    max-height: 290px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 5px;
}

.product-page-box {
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin-left: 250px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    background: #fafafa;
    height: 540px;
    max-width: 400px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.product-page-thumbnail {
    max-width: 360px;
    width:100%;
    max-height: 500px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 5px;
}

.wrap{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 30px;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.box{
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.add-wishlist{
    margin-top: -300px;
    padding-left: 205px;
    position: absolute;
}

.product-heart-icon{
    display: flex;
    margin: 5px;
     
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size:16px;
    color: black;
    padding: 5px;
}

.text{
    text-align: left;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    color:black;
    line-height: 1em;
}

.bold {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.transparentbtn {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: gray;
    border-style: solid;
    color: black;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1px;
}

.row{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

ul{
    list-style: none;
}

.footer{
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    margin-top: 70px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 35px;
    width: 100%;
}

.footer-col{
   width: 25%;
   padding: 0 15px;
}

.footer-col h4{
    font-size: 17px;
    color: black;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    font-weight: 600;
    position: relative;
    font-family:'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
}

.footer-col ul li:not(:last-child){
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.footer-col ul{
    padding-left: 0;
}

.footer-col ul li a{
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: black;
    display: block;
}

.footer-col .social-links a{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    font-size: 22px;
    margin:0 10px 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: black;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.footer-col .social-links a:hover{
    color: #24262b;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

/*responsive*/
@media(max-width: 767px){
  .footer-col{
    width: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
}

@media(max-width: 574px){
  .footer-col{
    width: 100%;
}
}

#header-wishlist{
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 215px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}

#header-cart{
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}

#cart-item{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family:'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

/* Here, product-name is the brand */
#product-name{
    padding-top: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family:'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

#product-description{
    font-size:15px;
}

#product-price{
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}

/* Here, product-name is the brand */
#product-page-name{
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 88px;
    font-family:'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

#product-page-description{
    font-size:18px;
}

#product-page-price{
    padding-top: 70px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}

#product-page-inventory{
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

#dropdownMenuButton{
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: grey;
    border-style: solid;
    color: black;
}

#productPageWishlist {
    min-width: 300px;
    font-size: 17px;
    margin-bottom: 13px;
}

#productPageCart {
    margin-left: 33px;
    font-size: 18px;
    min-width: 140px;
}

#limited-stock {
    color:red;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

I have tried applying width:100% and margin:0 to body, but it is still not working.

Comment: First of all, fix your broken HTML. A `header` element does _not_ belong between `head` and `body`, it belongs _into_ `body`.

Comment: @CBroe Understood, I have fixed it already. It's my first time building a website, so there'll be some errors. Please help

Comment: The problem appears to be, that you are using a `.row` element as child of your `header` element. But `.row` applies -12px margin on either side, which in combination with the 100% wide header, causes this problem. You should only put rows into container elements: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/layout/containers/ (So in this case, _add_ a `.container-fluid` element into your `header` first, and then the row into that. Or one of the other container classes, if you don't want it to be full width at all display sizes.)

Comment: @CBroe I have removed the row element. It works now, thank you!

Comment: Using columns outside of a row, can also potentially lead to problems. Best if you really just follow the BS grid structure, as intended.

Comment: @CBroe I see, I have added the container-fluid, as you have explained. Thank you!

Comment: Putting the container class onto the header element, without introducing an extra element, should also work here: `<header class="container-fluid">`

Answer (score 0):

First Make sure there are no stray margin or padding values on the navbar or footer:

```
.navbar,
.footer {
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
}
```

Then explicitly set widths on the navbar, content area, and footer:

```
.navbar, 
.content,
.footer {
    width: 100vw;
}
```

or try adding overflow: hidden

```
.navbar,
.footer {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```